# Why is \W meta character not working properly in this Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello I'm having trouble understanding this regex.

```
'^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d\W]).*$'
```

It should match **ZXC!"#zxc123**, which it does in an online JS regex tester, but when i try it in the application i am working on, it wont match that. It seems to require the letter **W**, which i assume comes from the non-word selector \W.

So the case is, that it works in an online tester, but not with actual JS.

I've set up an example on Fiddle, so you can see for yourself.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var inputField = $('#regex');
    
    inputField.on('input', function(e){
        var inputValue = $(e.currentTarget).val();
        
        MatchString(inputValue);
    });

    
    function MatchString(str){
        var matches = str.match('^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d\W]).*$');
        
        if(matches){
            $('#output').text('Matches')
        }
        else{
            $('#output').text('Not matching')
        }  
    }
    
    MatchString(inputField.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="regex" value='ZXC!"#zxc!"#'/>
<p id="output"></p>
```

I've tested the regex [on regex101](http://www.regex101.com)

I really hope for a explanation, because this seems very odd to me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that `_` is not included in the `(?=.*[\d\W])` check. Is that OK with you? If you want to say one character not lowercase/uppercase a-z, then just write it directly `[^a-zA-Z]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your syntax is not right for regex. In JS regex should be wrapped as `/.../` where `/` is called regex delimiter.

Also your regex can be refactored for efficiency as this:

```
/^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[\d\W]).{8,}$/
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qrnw39kh/2/)

Comment: String.match automatically converts strings to regex by passing it to `new RegExp()`. So this is not the reason. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: That was the reason because `\w` becomes `w` unless enclosed in `/` Or use double escaping.

Comment: Great that works! I changed it to a regex instead of a string. Javascript sees the text as a regex, once i added the regex delimiter. I completely forgot about the delimiter, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When I removed the ' from your regex, it worked fine.

```
^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d\W]).*$
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that inside strings `"\d"` will be escaped to `"d"` and `"\W"` will be escaped to `"W"` due to backslash substitution rules for strings (see the [string literal documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#String_literals)).

So if you want the backslash character you need to escape it:

```
str.match('^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\\d\\W]).*$');
```

Alternatively you can use a regex literal:

```
str.match(/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d\W]).*$/);
```